# Tomcat + Liferay + lib/ext caching?

Tags: tomcat, liferay, tomcat7, hook, liferay-6

:)

We're having problems, we're in liferay version 6.1 and we're making a jar lib that use a hook (the hook is lunched when we make "update" in JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil), where are writing logs.debug in code but the old logs are shown but the new ones do not, it seems that it is caching but I have never seen something like that, it is impossible for us to advance with ease when it seems that tomcat does not recognize the changes, does anyone know what could be happening?

Steps to change the library:

1. Shutdown Tomcat
2. Remove library
3. Copy new library
4. Remove work & temp
5. Start Tomcat

Does anyone know something?

Thank you :)

Edited:
The jar update a row of AssertLink and call to super.update, when the update is finoshed, call a method (in jar shared) that get the text of a field in the content of this article that we have updated, the error appears when call to method for get the text, because we forget split the text.

Comment: Just to clarify. You have created a shared jar that is used in a hook that has a service wrapper to modify JournalArticleLocalService update method? What is the jar doing?

Comment: @MiroslavLigas see edit pls :)

Comment: how do you refer to the lib in the hook? If you have the lib in the shared tomcat folder it should be marked as provided so that it does not get bundled into the hook war.

Comment: @MiroslavLigas whe marked as provied, and we set the jar into lib/ext forlder. The hook and the jar compile well and work well but when change a code (with a if for example) and complie and back to set into lib/ext this if is not visible, we have see into jar file and this if is writed but the tomcat don’t read this version is like if tomcat read the version that haven’t the if :(

Comment: hmm, the clean of the server should get rid of the old version. Can it not be that you have the class 2x on the classloader? Try to remove the lib completely if the code will break.

Comment: Yeah :) the code break, we tried to remove the lib and the result is good (break all), but when back to set the jar into lib again back the issue, i will see we have class 2x but i think that no :(. It’s rare because there are times that it does it and there are times that it does not. The more coherent is think that is cacjhing but its crazy never i’ve seen a lib caching :(

Comment: the only thing that can cache would the tomcat but you already addressed that. Try to run a deep find for the file name in all jar files from tomcat home and down. This could show a name clash. You should be able to find a bash script for that.